# STL const_iterator cast -- compiler differences

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, visual-studio-2013, const-iterator

I'm porting a big chunk of code from gcc to Visual Studio 2013.  The following code sample works fine (!) on gcc 4.4, but compiling `begin()` and `end()` fails on VS2013 with:

> error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'unsigned char *' to 'std::_Vector_const_iterator>>'

```
class foo {
    unsigned char* value;
    int length;

    std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator begin();
    std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator end();
};

std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator foo::begin() {
    return std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator(value);
}

std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator foo::end() {
    return std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator(value + length);
}
```

Given that I don't want to rewrite the whole thing, is there a portable way to create these const_iterators?

Comment: Sorry, you were taking advantage of an implementation detail of gcc that doesn't exist in VS2013. The definition of `const_iterator` is outside of your control, and it doesn't include the ability to take an arbitrary pointer.

Comment: Can you change the type from `std::vector<unsigned char*>::iterator` to `const unsigned char*` or a custom iterator?

Comment: Or, if `value` is always from a vector, can you change it to `std::vector<unsigned char*>::iterator value;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no portable way to do what you're attempting because there is no requirement that a `(const_)iterator` be constructible from a pointer to the underlying value type. libstdc++ happens to provide such a constructor but the VS standard library implementation doesn't. Instead, its `(const_)iterator` constructor takes a pointer to the underlying value type and a pointer to the container itself, which it uses to perform additional validation during debug builds.

The easiest solution is to replace `std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator` with `unsigned char const *`. A raw pointer falls in the RandomAccessIterator category, which is the same as `vector::(const_)iterator`s.

```
unsigned char const *foo::begin() {
    return value;
}

unsigned char const *foo::end() {
    return value + length;
}
```

---

If you needs the iterator to be a class type, then you'll need to create a custom iterator. While this can be done from scratch, it's a lot easier to use [Boost.IteratorFacade](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html), which will provide a bunch of the necessary boilerplate that goes into constructing a custom iterator.

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>

struct const_foo_iterator : boost::iterator_facade<const_foo_iterator,
                                                    unsigned char const,
                                                    boost::random_access_traversal_tag>
{
  const_foo_iterator() = default;
  const_foo_iterator(unsigned char const *iter) : iter(iter) {}
private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

    void increment() { ++iter; }
    void decrement() { --iter; }
    void advance(std::ptrdiff_t n) { iter += n; }

    std::ptrdiff_t distance_to(const_foo_iterator const& other) const
    { return iter - other.iter; }

    bool equal(const_foo_iterator const& other) const
    { return this->iter == other.iter; }

    unsigned char const& dereference() const { return *iter; }
    unsigned char const* iter = nullptr;
};

const_foo_iterator foo::begin() {
    return value;
}

const_foo_iterator foo::end() {
    return value + length;
}

static_assert(std::is_same<std::iterator_traits<const_foo_iterator>::value_type,
                           unsigned char>::value, "value_type");
static_assert(std::is_same<std::iterator_traits<const_foo_iterator>::pointer,
                           unsigned char const *>::value, "pointer");
static_assert(std::is_same<std::iterator_traits<const_foo_iterator>::iterator_category,
                           std::random_access_iterator_tag>::value, "iterator_category");
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b07e319e9792043e)

Comment: Thank you, pretty much what I was afraid of -- no get-out-of-jail-free card. The sample shows the essential elements of conflicts in a mass of code I didn't write and was hoping to avoid performing major surgery on.

Comment: This answer again assumes that the calling code is generic enough not to care about the actual type of the iterator. But what if the rest of the code contains lines like `for (std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator iter = my_foo.begin(); iter != my_foo.end(); ++iter)` all over the place?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yep, there's no way around that

Comment: @ChristianHackl that's one good reason why they invented `auto`.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how the `begin()` and `end()` functions are used. If the callers of those functions actually expect a `std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator` (rather than being generic enough not to care about the exact type), then you have to search for different solutions.

Rather than changing the interface of the class, you could then try to implement a workaround in its implementation. What's the `value` pointer needed for? Who else has access to it? If it's a private member, then just replace it with an actual `std::vector<unsigned char>`, and use its `data()` member function (C++11) or `&value[0]` (pre C++11) to pass a pointer where one is expected.